# Resource not being deleted when calling destroy action [Rails 7]

Tags: activerecord, minitest, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm relatively new to rails, and I am working through a tutorial. The problem has been pointed out by one of the unit tests (using rails Minitest).

Here `test/controllers/carts_controller_test.rb` I assert that the number of carts has decremented by 1 after calling delete.

```
test "should destroy cart" do
    post line_items_url, params: { product_id: products(:ruby).id }
    @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])

    assert_difference("Cart.count", -1) do
      delete cart_url(@cart)
    end

    assert_redirected_to store_index_url
  end
```

This maps to my destroy action in `controllers/carts/controller.rb` seen below

```
def destroy    
    @cart.destroy! if @cart.id == session[:cart_id]
    @cart.save
    session[:cart_id] = nil

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to store_index_url,
        notice: 'Your cart is currently empty' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

However, when I run `bundle exec rails test` I get the following output:

```
# Running:

.............F

Failure:
CartsControllerTest#test_should_destroy_cart [...test/controllers/carts_controller_test.rb:46]:
"Cart.count" didn't change by -1.
Expected: 2
  Actual: 3


rails test test/controllers/carts_controller_test.rb:42

................

Finished in 0.651308s, 46.0612 runs/s, 98.2638 assertions/s.
30 runs, 64 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

When I try to delete with a button rendered in an ERB template

```
<%= button_to 'Empty Cart', cart, method: :delete,
  class: "ml-4 rounded-lg py-1 px-2 text-white bg-green-600" %>
```

I can see the following error:
`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/carts"):`
But, when I crosscheck by running `bundle exec rails routes` I can confirm that the route does indeed exist:

```
DELETE /carts/:id(.:format) carts#destroy
```

I'm not sure what is not working here, and would love to get some suggestions. I have tried searching through other posts, and worked with Bard, and have not been able to find a solution that works. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The routing error indicates that you're hitting the correct route, but with no cart ID. You should check the HTML of your button to see if the ID is in the link. If not, try replacing `cart` with `@cart` in `button_to`.  You also don't need to call `@cart.save` after `@cart.destroy!`

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I needed to update my button to call `carts_url(@cart)` to fix the delete on the UI side. However, my test is still failing. Whenever I call the destroy action the length of my carts array stays the same.